# C++ detached thread bug

Tags: c++, c++17

After spending one day trying to solve a mysterious bug, I seek your help.

When I run the code bellow, do you understand why the output with "Hello 3" is duplicated ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>
#include <unistd.h>

template <class Fn, class... Args>
inline decltype(auto) runTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    try {
        return std::invoke(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    } catch (...) {
        std::terminate();
    }
}

struct RunTerminateOnExceptionInvoker {
        template <class Fn, class... Args>
        decltype(auto) operator()(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) const {
            return runTerminateOnException(std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
};

template <class Fn, class... Args>
inline decltype(auto) runAsyncTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    usleep(1000);
    return std::async(std::launch::async, RunTerminateOnExceptionInvoker(), std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <class Fn, class... Args>
inline void runOnDetachedThreadTerminateOnException(Fn&& fn, Args&&... args) {
    usleep(1000000);
    std::thread(RunTerminateOnExceptionInvoker(), std::forward<Fn>(fn), std::forward<Args>(args)...).detach();
}

struct A {
        template <class T>
        static void g(double x, const std::shared_ptr<std::string> &s) {
            T t{};
            std::cout << "g() : x = " << x << ", *s = " << *s << ", t = " << t << std::endl;
        }

        static void f(double x, std::shared_ptr<std::string> &s1, std::shared_ptr<std::string> &s2, std::shared_ptr<std::string> &s3) {
            printf("Coucou 1\n");
            runAsyncTerminateOnException(g<double>, x, s1); // Working
            printf("Coucou 2\n");
            auto future1 = runAsyncTerminateOnException(g<double>, x, s2); // Working
            printf("Coucou 3\n");
            runOnDetachedThreadTerminateOnException(g<double>, x, s3); // Working
        }
};

int main() {
    auto s1 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello 1");
    auto s2 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello 2");
    auto s3 = std::make_shared<std::string>("Hello 3");
    A::f(10., s1, s2, s3);
    printf("Coucou 4\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
Coucou 1
g() : x = 10, *s = Hello 1, t = 0
Coucou 2
Coucou 3
g() : x = 10, *s = Hello 2, t = 0
Coucou 4
g() : x = 10, *s = Hello 3, t = 0
g() : x = 10, *s = Hello 3, t = 0
```

[Live run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8893eae7d55f36d8)

Thank you

Comment: The usual underlying reason for duplicate output in such cases in glibc is stdout flush caused by the implicit exit() at the end of main finds the output buffer while the thread is in the write() syscall. The thread would mark it written when the syscall returns, but flush sees it "unwritten" and issues it's own write()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have undefined behaviour here. Since the thread is detached, you're not guaranteeing that `*s3` will live for as long as the detached thread does. `main` is ending before your detached worker thread has finished executing, and all those strings go out of scope.

You have to pass your shared pointers by value to actually get their reference counting ability. At the moment, for each test, you're just passing a single `shared_ptr` instance around by reference, which isn't particularly useful.

**If you pass them by value into `A::f`, [things work as expected](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb0a48520f91d806).**

I can't *quite* work out what magic the compiler is doing in your case, and am slightly surprised at this specific result, but fortunately I can just say "it's UB" and leave things there ;)

Frankly I'm not even sure whether letting a detached thread run past the end of `main` is valid, but I'll let someone else tackle that aspect.

Comment: Many thanks. It's the first time I use a smart pointer, now I know I have to use them only by value.
After removing the reference and constness of those smart pointers on A::f and A::g it's working as expected

Comment: Now with the correct use of the shared pointers I don't think it's possible that the detached thread run past the end of main. Don't  you think ?

Comment: @infiniteLoop: _"Now with the correct use of the shared pointers I don't think it's possible that the detached thread run past the end of main"_ Why not?

Comment: @infiniteLoop: _"now I know I have to use them only by value"_ That's not always true. But it's true here.

Comment: After looking into it it seems that when the main function exits, then any detached thread is suspended and killed with the main thread, with no stack unwinding

Comment: I'm not convinced. `std::thread`'s constructor copies the arguments for the new thread, and so I don't see any lifetime issues with the `shared_ptr`s.

Comment: @T.C.: It's getting references, not copies. I demonstrated that dropping the refs solves the problem.

Comment: No, `std::thread`'s constructor does the copy itself. The only way the new thread doesn't get copies is if the code passed a `reference_wrapper` or equivalent.

Comment: @T.C.: Then I invite you to explain the results.

Comment: Cubbi explained it pretty well in his comment on the question. The "dropping the refs solves the problem" is just coincidence.

Comment: @T.C.: Hmm yeah you're right. I can't even get it to compile without a `const` on the ref, which (if indirectly) backs that up. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a0f6e998d8dca9c0 The results seem _incredibly_ co-incidental, but regardless I don't know what I was thinking with this

Comment: Perhaps if Cubbi had written that information in an _answer_ rather than putting it in a comment, it would have been subject to the same scrutiny and the OP would have had a better chance at getting the right answer. OFC my hands are tied now cos accepted